# PersistJS the call back function is not working

Tags: javascript, html, persistjs

I have found a good library to handle client storage, the latest version could be found here
https://github.com/jeremydurham/persist-js

But the one thing does not work is the call back function

```
var result = store.get('saved_data', function (ok, val) {
            console.log(ok, val);
        });
```

I could retrieve `result` successfully except the call back function was not working.
Any one help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no callback for PersistJS.  Just use `result` as needed.